# Android phones using wrong drawable folder

Tags: android, android-emulator, drawable, android-screen

I currently have all the standard drawable folders set up for my app on 2.3.3. (ldpi hdpi mdpi xhdpi) However, whenever I run the app on a 240dpi screen (hdpi) it uses the resources found in drawable-mdpi not drawable-hdpi. When I delete the mdpi folder everything work perfectly. Testing on the other screen densities works great. Just not hdpi screens. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing some declarations in my manifest file. Adding these fixed my problem.

```
   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
```

AND

```
    <supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

240dpi screen take only ldpi drawable folder if there is no ldpi drawable it will autometically
get mdpi drawable....
the hdpi drawable means high density pixel(480dpi)

Comment: I believe that is for screen size, not density. For density hdpi starts at 240dpi and ldpi starts at 120dpi